# How to check if hbase table exists from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hbase, hdfs

I have this bash script from which I need to check if an hbase table exists and accordingly I need to print the message. Below is what I tried.

```
doesTableExist=$(echo -e "exists '$base_table_name' | hbase shell")

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo [BYOA_HIVE_INGEST] [INFO] "Table already exists"
else
    echo [BYOA_HIVE_INGEST] [ERROR] "Table does not exist"
fi
```

Below is how I run the script.

```
sh test.sh $base_table_name = test
```

But this prints that the table exists all the time, irrespective of whether it exists or not. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is right, the way you are passing the variable value to the script is wrong, it should have been,

```
base_table_name="test" sh test.sh
```

The general syntax to set a variable or variables and then run a command is something like

```
FOO=bar somecommand someargs
```

If your return code is incorrect for all cases you can try searching on the command output directly like,

```
if echo -e "exists '$base_table_name'" | hbase shell 2>&1 | grep -q "does exist" 2>/dev/null 
then
    echo "[BYOA_HIVE_INGEST] [INFO] Table already exists"
else
    echo "[BYOA_HIVE_INGEST] [ERROR] Table does not exist"
fi
```

With the `-q` flag and `stderr` redirection to `NULL`, if the string is found, the return code of `grep` should satisfy the `if-clause`.

Comment: Actually the variable is getting set, the way I pass it. I have added an argument passing logic to get the variable names. I can print them as well. Its just that I dont get the correct result for the given name

Comment: @mayooran I guarantee the variable is not getting set the way you pass it. It may *already* be set because of something you did before, but they way you describe passing it does *not* work.

Comment: Hey I tried the updated answer. Still no luck. I am printing the variable values inside the script. They are actually set there. Right values are getting printed. It seems like the command is not getting executed through hbase. Something wrong with how its piped? :(

Comment: @mayooran: Can u check my latest update once? Run it once as I mentioned before, `base_table_name="test" sh test.sh`

Comment: @Inian It'd be much better to include the entire strings to be `echo`ed in quotes, otherwise things like `[BYOA_HIVE_INGEST]` will be treated as a shell wildcard, and if there happen to be any files named e.g. "A", "B", etc in the current working directory it'll list those instead of the expected string.